# How to insert each row in php code within // slash slash?

Tags: php, comments

How to insert each row in php code within `//` slash slash (in sublime text for web programming)? I want to do it like this with Key combinations.

```
//<? php
//$printit=curl_exec($ch);
//echo $printit;
//curl_close($ch);
//?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to comment out or uncomment the selected text or current line:

- Windows: <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>**Command ⌘**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>

Comment: is anybody changed my comment ? this is not my answer